# Executing a WPF .exe program from an email link

Tags: wpf

I have been trying to do this without luck. What I'm trying to do is use an Outlook email link to run a local WPF exe with a parameter. I have been trying several things. First I created a .bat file and tried to kick it off directly from the email link (and Word link):

c:\users\steve\debug\MasterPage.bat 100

The batch files looks like this:

C:\users\steve\debug\MasterPage.exe %1

So that doesn't work so I changed the link to point to a html file running a JavaScript function calling the exe directly:

```html
    function callProgram()
    {
        var objShell = new ActivexObject("Shell.Application");

        objShell.ShellExecute("cmd.exe", "C:\\cd C:\\Debug\\MasterPage.exe 1", "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32", "open", 1);    
    }
```

Nothing seems to work. If anyone can help please do.

Comment: I got it working on my local machine with the following:

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```html
script language=JavaScript

function launchExecutable(executableFullPath)

{

 var shellActiveXObject = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

 shellActiveXObject.Run(executableFullPath, 1, false);

 shellActiveXObject = null;

}

script
```